# Where can I view the Google Analytics iOS crash logs?

Tags: ios, google-analytics-api, crash-reports

In Google Analytics native SDK for iOS (v2 Beta) I found the following line in there documentation:

```
// Optional: automatically track uncaught exceptions with Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
```

Does this mean, that Google Analytics now also supports crash logs tracking (like BugSense or Crittercism)? But where do I find them in the online interface of Google Analytics?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: Google Analytics iOS crash logs]

On the left panel, expand the Engagement menu and then click on Crash and Exceptions

**Update:**

Now it is GoogleAnalytics V4 and for that go

> Behavior -> Crashes and Exceptions

[image]

Comment: Good to know upfront but what about the stack traces? Can I download them or see them? Of course you will have to symbolicate the crash logs to really know what's causing your app to crash!

Comment: Your can export the crash log from GA but the log information is very basic like that:
"NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: <redacted> <redacted> _CF_forwarding_prep_0 <redacted> -[YOURViewController viewDidLoad] <redacted> <r"

I don't know what do you mean about "stack traces" but based on GA document i think it's just a way to push log to GA.

"When using automatic exception measurement, keep in mind the following:
- All exceptions sent using automatic exception measurement are reported as fatal in Google Analytics.
- The description field is automatically populated using the stack trace."

Comment: I just gave it a try and forced a crash in my app. All I got in GA was the first 200 something characters of the complete crash log: `NSInvalidArgumentException Trace: -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] -[__NSArrayM addObject:] -[AccordionViewController viewDidAppear:] -[UIViewContr`This is not enough. Testflight for example can do way more. I was just hoping that I can use GA for that too. I will have to keep using Testflight then.

Comment: iTunes Connect's crash report logging has improved considerably since this question was posted and you can find fairly detailed crash logs there.  With the caveat that users have to have allowed them to be uploaded to Apple.

Comment: @CarlosP 99% users never allow to report crashes so you never get crash logs. It's useless, so go with 3rd party crash reporting. The best free to this day is crashlytics.

Comment: I am not able to find out crash report section. I have looked all the sections that are described in all answers.  I am using Google Analytics version 3.15 (latest). Please let me know where can I see crash report?

Answer (score 4):

Look in **Behavior** > **Crashes and Exceptions**.

Answer (score 1):

**Reporting --> Behavior --> Crashes and Exceptions**

http://analytics.blogspot.in/2013/02/5-things-you-should-be-doing-with.html